# How to hide security node and logins from some users in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

We are using SQL Server 2012.
I'm granting access to some one from out side my company.
I hide all Databases except his one.

Is there any possible way to hide all users and logins?
We want him to have information as few as possible about our server at SSMS.

How can we do this?

Comment: You cannot hide them but you can take away the permission to change/alter them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deny [VIEW ANY DATABASE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077(v=sql.105).aspx) to the public role. However, after doing that, all logins without this permission will only see the databases that they own, along with master and tempdb.

Logins in only the public role can not view other logins, so as long as you leave them out of server roles, that issue shouldn't be an issue for you either. See [sys.server_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) permissions for more details.

> Any login can see their own login name, the system logins, and the fixed server roles. To see other logins, requires ALTER ANY LOGIN, or a permission on the login.